# Apache replication

Tags: apache-2.2, replication

I don't know what I need to search for.

I need information about how to "replicate" an Apache server, if one would go down another would take over.

Also the Apache server holds a lot of data files. How is it possible to manage and store the files in the best way (also some kind of replication)?

Comment: Failover is the typical descriptor for switching to a secondary node. It really sounds like you are trying to setup a high availability cluster, possibly with a distributed/network filesystem (e.g. GlusterFS or DRBD with GFS2) to keep copies of your data synchronized across nodes. You will to monitor the health of your nodes (e.g. using Heartbeat/Corosync) and manage the resources on them (e.g. using Pacemaker). With multiple nodes, you may also need a load balancer (e.g. HAProxy, or even Nginx). A configuration manager (e.g. Puppet, Chef) may also be helpful with more complex setups.

Comment: Why do you write your answers up as comments ?

Comment: @Iain: I consider it an annoying personality quirk of mine. The 'answer-like' comments I post are usually because I am not upto writing up a full answer at that moment (busy, lazy, etc); or because I am unsure of my solution (which makes it more of a suggestion). With few exceptions, if I post something as an answer, I try to explain some of the rationale behind the answer - the 'why' is often more important to me than the end result. I usually try to revisit questions I have commented on though, and will 'upgrade' my comment to an answer if there are no answers that cover the same material.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want some sort of High Availability configuration, such as that provided by [Linux-HA](http://www.linux-ha.org).  For the data files, I would use [DRBD](http://www.drbd.org/), which is a way of replicating a block device between two machines (although typically only one machine will use it at once -- which is fine, because you've only got one machine running apache at once).

Personally, though, I'd probably work on getting my MTBF and MTTR down nice and low, and not worry about HA, in almost all circumstances -- the added complexity of the setup makes the chances of accidentally taking down your service much higher, and the costs of extra hardware and expertise to manage the whole shebang makes the HA requirement hard to justify in most cases.

Comment: Big +1 on the second paragraph, regarding the extra complexity, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The term you are looking for is 'failover' - essentially, the automated switching to a secondary resource when the primary resource fails.

While setting up a server cluster is both a great learning experience and a lot of fun, it easily becomes a complex task, and shouldn't be undertaken lightly. Explore other alternatives first.

It really sounds like you are trying to setup a high availability cluster. Let's say you have two nodes - there are (at least) two approaches:

- Active/Passive - one node will be serving the data, the other will be kept up to date, and in the event of the 'active' node failing, will take over as the active node.
- Active/Active - both nodes will be able to serve data - and both must be kept up to date. The added complexity here (beyond file conflicts), is presenting both nodes as a single front to the user (the benefit, of course, is in load balancing).

**Cluster Basics**

Consider, for a moment what would be required for even a simple cluster:

- Each node would need to know the status/health of the other node. This is typically accomplished by sending 'heartbeats' at a predetermined interval. Additionally, in a multi-node cluster, there is usually a master node - this same layer usually determines such a role. Heartbeat and Corosync are commonly used packages for this purpose (messaging layer). If the other nodes stop receiving the heartbeat from a particular node, they will restructure the cluster to omit that node (and possibly elect a new master node).
- Your cluster needs to control individual resources (e.g. Apache) - in some cases, you want only one instance of a certain service running at any time in your cluster. Pacemaker is commonly used as the cluster resource manager.

**File Replication**

Now you have the problem of keeping your files in sync between nodes. Since these are two separate nodes, the data must be replicated over the network.

- In an active/passive setup, only the active node will have read/write access to the data - the other node may not even have read access. A common example of such a setup will use DRBD (a kernel module and userland scripts) in a Primary/Secondary configuration. When the primary node fails, the secondary node can be promoted and will gain full access to its local copy of data (which has been replicated from the primary node).
- In an active/active setup, both nodes must be able to read and (usually) write the data. DRBD (setup as dual-primary) can be used for this (together with a cluster-aware filesystem such as GFS2 or OCFS2). Alternatively, you can use a distributed file system such as GlusterFS - which offers more features than DRBD (and is easier to setup) - but has additional overhead. With both nodes able to write to the same resource, the chance of conflicts, and 'split-brain' scenarios is much higher.

**Load Balancing**

In a cluster where both nodes are active and setup to serve requests, you need to send requests to each node. Typically this is accomplished with a load balancer which will sit in front of your cluster nodes. Depending on your needs, simple and efficient layer 3 (i.e. network) load balancers exist (such as Linux Virtual Server), or more complex layer 7 (i.e. application/content-aware) load balancers (e.g. HAProxy). Some web servers (e.g. Nginx) also function as simple load balancers. The problem of course, then becomes one of how to deal with a failure of your load-balancer (so you may need two load-balancers setup for failover).

**Configuration Managers**

With all these various components interacting, you may want something to simplify the process of maintaining each node and managing the various configurations - configuration managers such as Puppet and Chef serve this purpose.

Comment: As someone who is not a computer person, I am very aware of how impossible it can seem to delve into a complex topic without even knowing what things are called - it makes searching much harder than it needs to be. That said, it is possible, and amazingly cool to play with once you manage to wrap your head around it all.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend [DRBD](http://www.drbd.org/) + [corosync](http://corosync.org) You can find sufficient documentation at [Clusters from scratch](http://www.clusterlabs.org/doc/en-US/Pacemaker/1.1/html/Clusters_from_Scratch/)

Answer (score 0):

Simply run two or more web servers behind a load balancer. For most websites, this is a simpler and more natural solution than a high-availability cluster. Depending on the nature of your site, you might even be able to use round-robin DNS instead of a load balancer.

For the data files, you could use some form of shared storage, either NAS (nfs or cifs) or SAN; or let each web server have its own local storage which you synchronise at intervals.

To update web servers (whether to patch the software or update the files being served) you can take one server out of the load balanced pool, update it, test the updates, then (if all is well) place that server back into the pool and move on to the next one.